# How to declare a pipe globally to use in different modules?

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, angular-module

I have a custom pipe named **`CurrConvertPipe`**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {LocalStorageService} from './local-storage';
@Pipe({name: 'currConvert', pure: false})
export class CurrConvertPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private currencyStorage: LocalStorageService) {}

  transform(value: number): number {
     let inputRate = this.currencyStorage.getCurrencyRate('EUR');
    let outputputRate = this.currencyStorage.getCurrencyRate(localStorage.getItem('currency'));
    return value / inputRate * outputputRate;
  }
}
```

I need to use this in two different modules, `Module1` and `Module2`.
When I import in `Module1` and `Module2`, I get an error saying it should be declared in a higher level module.

So I declare the pipe inside the **`app.module.ts`**

```
import './rxjs-extensions';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CurrConvertPipe } from './services/currency/currency-pipe';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        Module1,         
        Module2

    ],

    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CurrConvertPipe
    ],
    providers: [

    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But when I use it in `Module1`, it throws an error

> The pipe 'currConvert' could not be found

Answer (score 203, accepted):

In Angular a good technique for sharing common directives, components, pipes, etc. is to use a so called **shared module**.

Those modules declare and export common parts, to make them usable for any of your other modules.

> The [**fundamentals section**](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) of the angular documentation is a very good read about shared modules.

Let's take as example your `currConvert` pipe.

- Declare new NgModule called `ApplicationPipesModule`
- Add the pipe to the `declarations` and `exports` arrays of the `NgModule`-decorator metadata
- Add any modules that may be required for your pipe to work to the 
  `imports` array

  ```
  // application-pipes.module.ts
  // other imports
  import { CurrConvertPipe } from './{your-path}';

  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      // dep modules
    ],
    declarations: [ 
      CurrConvertPipe
    ],
    exports: [
      CurrConvertPipe
    ]
  })
  export class ApplicationPipesModule {}
  ```
- import the created `ApplicationPipesModule` module into the modules where your pipe is going to be used, by adding it to the `imports` array

  ```
  // my-module1.module.ts
  // other imports
  import { ApplicationPipesModule } from './{your-path}';   

  @NgModule({
   imports: [
     // other dep modules
     ApplicationPipesModule
   ],
   declarations: [],
   exports: []
  })
  export class MyModule1 {}
  ```

Comment: Not that it's your fault, but didn't work for me. I still get the Template parse errors. I've been debugging this thing for an hour, which is 55 minutes more than what it should take to set up a custom pipe. A very frustrating experience.

Comment: I have done same thing but I am getting error: "application-pipes.module.ts module not found"

Comment: Same concept can be used for reusing directives/components/services (except for service we need additional configuration). Nice explanation

Comment: Works perfect! Don't forget to add the NgModule import into the shared module. `import { NgModule } from '../../../../node_modules/@angular/core';`

Comment: I needed to add my shared module to both the app module imports and my page-level module imports. I don't know why. I hate that I had to flail around until I stumbled on this solution.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach cause multiple instances of a service?

Comment: I got an `NG6002: There is an error in this module` error. Was required to restart my `ng serve` for it to pick the new module up.

Answer (score 24):

you can use **Sharing Modules** for share your **service, directive, pipes, components**

you have to create an module and import the pipes ,directive, services or components and set the declaration, export and providers for the services.

import the sharing module in to where ever you want and use it.

basically pipes and directives declared and exported in NgModules meta data. 
for services define **forRoot** which returns the providers to access other modules.

- shareModule.ts

  ```
  import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
  import { appDirective } from './{your-path}';
  import { appPipe } from './{your-path}';
  import { appService } from './{your-path}';

  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      appPipe,
      appDirective
    ],
    exports: [
      appPipe,
      appDirective
    ]
  })
  export class SharingModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
      return {
        ngModule: SharingModule,
        providers: [ appService ]
      };
    }
  }
  ```
- my-module1.module.ts

  ```
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

  import { myComponent } from './{your-path}';

  import { SharingModule } from './{your-path}';

  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      myComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      SharingModule.forRoot()  
    ],
  })
  export class AppModule {}
  ```

Like wise you can do in othe moduls also.

Comment: [`ModuleWithProviders` without a generic is now deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/migration-module-with-providers). That code should now be `static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<SharingModule> {`

Answer (score 9):

Consider you have this structure:

```
app 
 -shared
   -components
     -DateComponentModule.ts
   -pipes
     -DatesPipe
     -DatesPipeModule.ts
     
 -SharedModule.ts
```

When you are using DatesPipeModule in DateComponentModule.

1. Declare and Export DatesPipe in DatesPipeModule
2. Now Import DatesPipeModule directly into DateComponentModule.

DatesPipeModule.ts

```
import { DatesPipe} from './{your-path}';

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [ 
    DatesPipe
  ],
  exports: [
    DatesPipe
  ]
})
export class DatesPipeModule{}
```

DateComponentModule.ts

```
import { DatesPipeModule} from './{your-path}';

@NgModule({
  imports: [DatesPipeModule],
  declarations: [],
  exports: []
})
export class DateComponentModule{}
```

You can also export it from `SharedModule` and import it in `DatesComponentModule.ts`, but `SharedModule` will not load before pipes, so it throws an error.

Comment: ohh i see the problem that you said: but SharedModule will not load before pipes, so it throws an error. thanks. I declared in the non shared module the pipe only for this module

Answer (score 6):

You should make a module, i.e. `SharedModule` and declare your pipe there. Then you should export pipe in `SharedModule` and import your `SharedModule` in both `Module1` and `Module2`. There's a great article in Angular's docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module

Comment: @Sajeetharan app.module _imports_ `Module1` and `Module2`, so pipe is *not* imported in these modules. If you import `SharedModule` in `Module1` then pipe gets imported in `SharedModule` and exports to `Module1`

Comment: The pipe has service dependency, how would you deal with that?

Comment: @Wildhammer think that service must come in same module with pipe

Comment: Then you'd have multiple instances of that service per import. That is usually not okay.

Answer (score 2):

If you generate a pipe using CLI for a shared module you will need to add the pipe to the 'exports' list manually. My pipe error'd in the browser until I added the pipe as an export in my shared module I imported/declared it in.