# Angular [innerHtml]: how to render additional elements inside an element with [innerHtml] directive

Tags: javascript, html, angular

An element with the [innerHtml] directive just seems to add the declared html string inside that element, and nothing more;

through [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inner-html-w9w21e?file=app/app.component.html), i was trying to add something inside such an element, to no avail;

`<div [innerHTML]="safeHtml(item.isi)"><p>new word - will not show</p></div>`

Is there a way to add some more HTML inside an element with the [innerHtml] directive? In other words, how can i make the stackblitz in the example work?

Comment: updated my working answer , check working code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inner-html-w1mxr8?file=app%2Fapp.component.html, same updated in my answer

Comment: please have look updated and let me know if there is any issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try by using `ElementRef`, if you want to append element not want to replace full html ,

html

```
<div #Container>
    add here 
 </div>
```

ts file

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  @ViewChild('Container') container: ElementRef ;

  content = [
   {judul: "Judul 1", isi:"<div id='title_1'>Isinya</div>"},
   {judul: "Judul 2", isi:"<div id='title_2'>pranay</div>"},
  ];

  ngAfterViewInit() { 
   this.content.forEach( (item,index) =>{
      this.container.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div id="title${index}">${item.judul}</div>`);
this.container.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `${item.isi}`);

   });
}
```

however elementref is not recommended way.

**output of above code**

[image]

you can see it adding content after , **add here** one by one

Find  : [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inner-html-w1mxr8?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

---

Instead of using function in your component (its not working as your html-template trying to pass html to your typscript file) , you should create pipe as below

html.pipe.ts

```
import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'html'
})
export class HtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
    transform(value) {
        return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    }
}
```

and use it like

html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of content">
 <h3 [innerHTML]="item.judul | html ">add</h3>
 <div [innerHTML]="item.isi | html "><p>new word</p></div>
</div>
```

Find  : [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inner-html-w1mxr8?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I am interested in how you get styles to be applied to html within the directive too? the css font style does not currently apply.

Comment: @Danoram - not getting you can you provide stackbiz , because i am not using directive approach,

Comment: I meant attribute directive `[innerHTML]`. I found the answer in another stackoverflow question. dw

Comment: @Danoram - [innerHTML]. is not directive, OP want to add html in given element dont want to replace thats why i given updated solution of Element ref ...

Comment: *Property bindings. doesn't matter I have found an answer to that plus directives etc. thanks

Comment: @Danoram - are you OP , you have two account ? , and provide link of answer

Comment: idk what you are talking about now. [this told me what i needed to know to get styles using innerHTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210786/style-not-working-for-innerhtml-in-angular-2-typescript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) I'm moving on with my life now. thanks

Comment: @Danoram- you shoudnt do this `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,` better to use senetizer as i given in my pipe code , and I am aksing are you the person who asked above question

Comment: No i'm not. I will keep this in mind. I appreciate all your answers here.

Answer (score 1):

why are you using [innerHTML] since your item.isi  is not an html element; we use innerHTML to render a html result; like if your item.isi is `<p>My name</p>`; if it is not a html element no use of using innerHTML, you can simply use {{item.isi}} inside your div, so you can render other html elements also

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question, using inner html replaces the inner html. Therefore the old value is replaced by the value from your object.

i understand you are following this approch as you want to display the value from the object.

So a better approach is using pipes. May be.
Just check this answer. If it helps.
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576420/how-to-declare-pipe-globally-to-use-in-different-modules)