# _co.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to display the `failedjobs` `array<any>` data in a reverse manner

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let failjob of failedjobs.slice().reverse()">
```

I'm getting an error as

> ERROR TypeError: _co.failedjobs.slice is not a function
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (FailedPage.html:13)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14655)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13802)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:14153)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14085)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13808)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:14153)
>       at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14111)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13803)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:14153)

What is the problem & how do I resolve it.

Comment: please provide minimal verifiable code...

Comment: Whatever `failedjobs` is (and we have no way of telling), it doesn't have a `slice` method. Why do you think it should?

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:ionic2] and [tag:ionic3] which are mutually exclusive. Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using ionic 3. I have scene `.slice().reverse()` in some of the post of stackoverflow & I have tried it. Intailly it worked but now it's displaying as error @Quentin

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Slice pipe or use custom pipe instead of calling the function slice().reverse()

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'reverse' })

export class ReversePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value) {
    return value.slice().reverse();
  }
}
```

and consume as

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let failjob of failedjobs | reverse">
```

Comment: I'm getting error as
`Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'reverse' could not be found ("
    <ion-list>

        <ion-item *ngFor="let fai[ERROR ->]ljob of failedjobs | reverse">   

          <ion-avatar item-start ion-checkbox checked="true">
"):`

Comment: you need to register the pipe in your module

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576420/how-to-declare-pipe-globally-to-use-in-different-modules

Comment: were you able to fix it